# cocoapods create private pods ,pod search fail

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

### cocoapods create private pods

> $ pod repo add XPFun http://gitlab.91jkys.com/iOS/XPFunList.git
>
> $ pod lib create XPFunList
>
> $ git add & commit & tag ...
>
> $ pod lib lint
>
> - XPFunList (0.1.0)
> - XPFunList passed validation.
>
> $ pod repo push XPFun XPFunList.podspec
>
> $ pod search XPFunList

### What happened instead?

> Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching XPFunList

### CocoaPods Environment

> $ pod --version
>
> $ 1.1.0
>
> $ gem --version
>
> $ 2.6.8
>
> $ ruby -v
>
> $ ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
>
> $ xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

### Project that demonstrates the issue

> $ pod repo list
>
> - master ...
> - XPFun  ...
> - 2 repos

`XPFunList.podspec`

```js
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'XPFunList'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'XPFunList.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
XPFunList function list
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'http://originxp.com'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'originxp' => 'originxp@163.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'http://gitlab.91jkys.com/iOS/XPFunList.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'XPFunList/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
end
```

### I tried this method

rm ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/search_index.json

Not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

`rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"`